# How do I turn off Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0 for a Spring Boot application without using Maven Profiles?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, swagger

I want to turn off Swagger when my Spring Boot app is in production. I woudl perfer not to use
profiles because I want finer grained control.

This is my configuration class for Swagger and the @ConditionalOnProperty I added:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    value="module.enabled",
    havingValue = "true",
    matchIfMissing = false)
public class SpringFoxConfig {
  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build();
  }
}
```

The application configuration file has these values:

```
    //The parameters visible in the Swagger UI
    application-description=@project.description@
    application-version=@project.version@
```

When I restarted my app using the command line,

> ./mvnw spring-boot:run

I can still see the Swagger UI when I go to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

I tried changing the SpringFoxConfig file to this:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class SpringFoxConfig {
  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build();
  }
}
```

and I started the Spring Boot application using the command line:

> ./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod

and when the app started, I could still see the Swagger UI when
I went to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Here is the POM file for my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <artifactId>SpringSandal</artifactId>
 <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   </dependency>
   <!-- dependencies for Swagger and OpenAPI 3.0 -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
     <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- end of dependencies for Swagger -->
   <dependency>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
     <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
         <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
         <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
       </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
 <groupId>com.example</groupId>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <name>SpringSandal</name>

 <parent>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <relativePath/>
   <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
   <java.version>11</java.version>
 </properties>

 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

</project>
```